# PostGIS get geometries within a radius of n meters using WGS84

Tags: postgis, wgs84, geography-data-type, geometry-data-type

```
select *
from zones z
where st_intersects(z.geom, st_Buffer(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(2.336031, 48.863172), 3857),1));
```

It looks like the `1` in the `st_buffer` is being interpreted as degrees, I need to find geometries within `n` meters of a given point.

I did find a reference to a new function (`st_Buffer_Meters`) but that didn't seem to do anything different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are particularly interested in using `meters` as the unit for the search, you can use geography data types instead of geometry types. All geography based calculations return values in meters. Also, `ST_DWITHIN` is designed for this type of queries:

```
select *
from zones z
where ST_DWITHIN(Geography(ST_Transform(z.geom,4326)), ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(2.336031 48.863172)'),10000000);
```

A test `zones` table as follows is used. The query will return the polygons if 10,000km is used and empty if 1,000km is used as radius.

```
/* DROP TABLE IF EXISTS zones; */
CREATE TABLE zones (name varchar, geom geometry);

INSERT INTO zones VALUES
 ('Polygon 1', 'POLYGON((-1 1.732,1 1.732,2 0,1 -1.732,
     -1 -1.732,-2 0,-1 1.732))'),
 ('Polygon 2', 'POLYGON((-1 1.732,-2 0,-1 -1.732,1 -1.732,
     2 0,1 1.732,-1 1.732))'),
 ('Polygon 3', 'POLYGON((1 -1.732,2 0,1 1.732,-1 1.732,
     -2 0,-1 -1.732,1 -1.732))'),
 ('Polygon 4', 'POLYGON((-1 1.732,0 1.732, 1 1.732,1.5 0.866,
     2 0,1.5 -0.866,1 -1.732,0 -1.732,-1 -1.732,-1.5 -0.866,
     -2 0,-1.5 0.866,-1 1.732))'),
 ('Polygon 5', 'POLYGON((-2 -1.732,2 -1.732,2 1.732,
     -2 1.732,-2 -1.732))');

ALTER TABLE zones
  ALTER COLUMN geom
  SET DATA TYPE geometry(Geometry,4326)
  USING ST_SetSRID(geom, 4326);
```

Comment: select *
from zones z
where st_intersects(st_transform(z.geom, 4326), ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(2.336031 48.863172 )'))

  So that doesn't return a result, which I know is incorrect.  I have the shapefile imported as srid 3857 and my lat long queries work.  This radius stuff is kind of stumping me though.

Comment: Ahh, ok.  when I transformed my geom coluymns to 4326 I started seeing some success